# arduino bluetooth, set led HIGH when no connection to device

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, led

it is possible to automatically set arduino LED to HIGH(off) when arduino bluetooth disconnect from android device?

the coding should be on arduino itself or android?

Comment: Well it depends on what hardware you are using and how bluetooth module communicates with Arduino board. Can you be more specific? What bluetooth module and board are you using?

Comment: bluetooth module connected to arduino using normal copper cable. im using DFRobot Bluetooth V3 and arduino nano.